# Заблокировать пользователя в ASP.NET MVC: нет таких классов в проекте

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, view

Хочу сделать в проекте возможность заблокировать пользователя в ASP.NET MVC. Делал всё по этой статье [Disable user in ASP NET identifier 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652118/disable-user-in-aspnet-identity-2-0/35310691)

Но не чего не получается. Вернее я не понял где найти `PasswordSignInAsync in ApplicationSignInManager` у меня таких нет. Это значит что просто логику не понял.

Может кто нибудь объяснить подробно, как сделать что бы только администратор мог заблокировать пользователя, если нужно.

Если есть более удобный вариант как это сделать, не такой как в статье. То объяснить его подробнее.

Comment: `ApplicationSignInManager` - это класс, который генерируется при создании проекта. Раз у вас его нет, вам надо его написать

Comment: @tym32167 думал так сделать, но где его делать то? Так и не понял. То есть, где создавать.

Comment: В смысле где? В проекте, у вас больше мест нет где классы хранить.

Comment: @tym32167 это да!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовал в свое время обходное решение в Core 2 работало. Эти поля есть и Core 2.1

В таблице AspNetUser за блокировку отвечает поле datetime LockoutEnd
Обычно Identity использует это поле для блокировки пользователя на время после N не удачных попыток входа.
Соответственно делал так:

Controller:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(string userId)
    {
        // получаем пользователя
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // получем список ролей пользователя

            return View(user);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("DeleteUser")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser2(string userId)
    {
        // получаем пользователя
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // Блокируем на 200 лет
            user.LockoutEnd = DateTime.Now.AddYears(200);
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            return RedirectToAction("UserList");
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```

Ну и где то в списке ставил кнопку:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@item.Id-2" asp-action="DeleteUser" asp-controller="Roles" asp-route-userId="@item.ApplicationUser.Id">Закрыть доступ</a>
```

Просто блокировал пользователя на 200 лет. Ну и соотвественно что бы разблокировать очищаем это поле. Есть ряд моментов которые стоит учесть.

1. Авторизированный пользователь не вылетит из сети. Решается путем принудительного выкидывания из системы.
2. При авторизации на основе Cooke (по умолчанию) пользователь сможет попасть в течении жизни Cooke (по умолчанию 30 минут). Решается обнулением токена.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Подробно и понятно! Буду пробовать!!!

Answer (score 2):

Там всё правильно написано и всё прекрасно работает для старых версий студии и старых шаблонов проекта asp.net mvc и core.

Классов ApplicationSignInManager и  PasswordSignInAsync у вас нет, потому что при создании проекта вы не выбрали пункты, которые бы сгенерировали данные файлы автоматически.

В пункте Change Authentication вам нужно выбрать пункт Individual User Account.

Для asp.net mvc:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для asp.net core:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно и написать руками, я как-то изучая эти проекты почти всё переписывал с нуля, но прямо говоря это очень большая работа, там только одних вьюх штук тридцать файлов и делать это стоит либо в целях глубокого изучения технологии, либо в целях написания очень кастомного решения. Во всех остальных случаях проще начинать с готового типового проекта.

---

Updated. Так было где-то до сентября 2018 года, однако с выходом 2.1 произошло значительное изменение - [identity стала подключаться](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) как отдельная Area (технически - как библиотека Razor Pages), поэтому все эти технические классы убраны внутрь и если вам нужно дефолтное приложение - то у вас не будет этих лишних файлов в приложении, а если вы захотите что-то нестандартное - тогда вы будете перекрывать своими файлами дефолтные настройки.

Во-первых, в проект теперь [можно скафолдить identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio): правый клик по веб-приложению - Add - New Scaffold Item - Identity - Identity

В появившемся окне выбираем что хотим переопределить и указываем класс dbcontext и пользователя. Это первое.

Во-вторых, есть небольшое описание от майкрософт как кастомизировать identity.  Описывается, [как поменять модель пользователя](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1), как сделать миграции. Однако нужно понимать, что уже та методика, которую вы видели в том вопросе - она уже не совсем подходит, так как нужно теперь проходить по разным страницам (файлам cshtml) и корректировать их codebehind-файлы (ну, так это по крайней мере называлось много лет назад, на текущий момент не знаю, какой принят термин).

Ну если в двух словах: после того как вы поправили модель, добавив поле IsEnabled, провели миграции, заскафолдили файл Register.cshtml - вам нужно поправить OnPost в Register.cshtml.cs:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
```

Чтобы при создании пользователя вписывался IsEnabled = True

И аналогично поправить SignIn (заскафолдить, переписать), чтобы заблокированные пользователи не могли войти.

Comment: @A K  Естественно я так и делал. и файлов этих нет.

Comment: @EugeneTM Поставьте Individual User Accounts - и будет. И в контроллерах и в представлениях.

Comment: @A K Я ставил. И в версии 2,0 и 2,1 нема их!

Comment: @EugeneTM Да, оказывается вы правы. Буквально месяц назад майкрософт всё поменяла в этой теме и теперь нужно скафолдить identity. Я дописал в вопрос общее направление, куда теперь двигаться (либо вы ищете старый шаблон идентити и можете использовать старое описание, как кастомизировать), либо тщательно изучаете новый подход, но имейте ввиду - я описал только общий подход, это не степ-бай-степ, поэтому если вам пока уровень не позволяет - можно застрять надолго. От меня же спасибо за то, что натолкнули на такую новую тему.

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться!